# Huawei Android Logcat not showing logs

Tags: android, android-logcat, huawei-mobile-services

All the existing solutions I found online recommend doing the following:
https://www.xda-developers.com/huawei-phones-disable-logcat-heres-how-to-restore-access/

However, on my phone, when I press on LOG settings, it brings me to this "MTKlogger" screen, which corresponds to nothing I've seen online.  I am using Huawei enjoy 5 (TIT-AL00).

Comment: Same thing in Huawei 4C Pro

Comment: Log.wtf() work for me at least :)

Answer (score 0):

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44200309/1147688) to make sure it isnot disabled in your FW/ROM. If so you can try with:

```
$ su
# setprop logcat.live=enable
```

If that doesn't work, you'd need to flash a new `/system/build.prop` file.