# Android doesn't show logcat messages

Tags: android, logcat

It is only showing the Error messages for my app. It is a navon platinum 10.
I tried setprop with log level with adb but no luck!

**UPDATE**

- android studio (latest)
- No Filter
- Device recognised by adb and Logcat (show only Error messages)
- android 6.0 Navon Platinum 10

Tried:

- `android:debuggable="true"`
- `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />`
- adb shell pm grant com.something.MyAppMame android.permission.READ_LOGS
- adb shell setprop log.tag.MyLogger VERBOSE

Comment: What IDE are you using ? Isn't there a filter on message type ? Is your device reconized ? Add more details about the setup/software please

Comment: Updated. Why for minuses????

Comment: Not enough details, I changed -1 in +1 after your edit. The only thing I can think of is the combobox on the bottom right that defines log level but I'm pretty sure you already know that :) That got my attention though I'll look later on my Android Studio what could go wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps first:
1. Go to the device tab, click your device. and go back to the logcat tab
2. You might have filter set.
3. You are probably viewing the wrong package.

And if problem still exists then try this method: 
Go to Windows - Preferences - Android - Logcat . On that page "Show logcat view if message priority is at least " select VERBOSE..

Comment: I see ONLY ERROR messages ON ALL applications. NO filters, NO regex, NO other things. And NO VERBOSE, INFO, etc, just ERROR. It is working for other android6 device, like Samsung Galaxy S7.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Android are you using?
On Android 6+, the following command should work: adb shell pm grant com.something.appname android.permission.READ_LOGS

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your AOS properties have not disabled logcat. Check with:

```
$ su
# getprop |grep logcat
```

This is usually done in `/system/build.prop`:

```
# Disable logcat
logcat.live=disable
```